# Superclass method is called from subclass object

Tags: java, inheritance

I have two classes SuperClass and SubClass,

```
class SuperClass{ public void count(){} }
class SubClass extends SuperClass { }
class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new SubClass().count();
    }
}
```

Here I used jdb to see how this code works, after making the Object of the SubClass, I expected the count method of the SubClass to be called as its inheriting the count method of the SuperClass, but the count method of SuperClass is being called.

I checked using "list" in jdb and it shows the line at count method of the SuperClass, why is this happening?

Comment: Because there is no `count` method in `SubClass` to call. In oops terms you've not overridden the `count` method in `SubClass`.

Comment: You didn't override anything...

Comment: This isn’t Java. Or if it is; it doesn’t compile.

Comment: @BoristheSpider That would be new SubClass(), I edited it now

Comment: @bulbus So until I override it will take the method from the SuperClass only?

Comment: Yes https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/inheritance.html

Comment: @Cloverr I wonder, why does this matter to you?

Comment: @Gendarme That program did compile on my machine, and I did that as I was just wondering if it really works as it is said

Answer (score 2):

When you call an object's method, Java checks that the method exists in the object. If so, it calls it, otherwise it checks for the existence in the parent class. And so on until method is found. 
Since you haven't overridden your method, the one which is called is the parent one.

Answer (score -1):

It should be something like below .

```
        class SuperClass{ public void count(){
    //if it is not overriden in the child class then this will get executed 
    }
 }
        class SubClass extends SuperClass { 
        public void count(){
        //If this exists, this will be executed otherwise the parent count() will be executed
        }
        }
        class Test
        {
            public static void main(String[] args)
            {
                new SubClass().count();
            }
        }
```

Comment: *Why* should it be something like that?

Comment: @Makoto Well I am reading his statement " I expected the count method of the SubClass to be called as its inheriting the count method of the SuperClass, but the count method of SuperClass is being called." but He didn't provide the implementation. I also have him the information in the comment section of each method.